# Android activity onPause() method

Tags: android, android-activity

In my current project, I have an activity named as `CalendarView.java` and an another launcher activity named as `FirstScreenActivity.java` which should always appear whenever user press home button/back button from `Calendar.java`. I also added interstitial ads in `FirstScreenActivity.java`.

Now, My problem is when I start `CalendarView.java` and ads appears, activity goes in `onPause()` state, now when I cancel those ads and comes back on `CalendarView.java` activity comes in `onResume()` state. Here I don't want my activity to finish in `onPause()` method, but I also want that is I'm pressing home button and then come back `FirstScreenActivity.java` should open.

Now What I want is, when I click home button in `CalendarView.java` and restart the project `FirstScreen.java` should appear, and when ads appear in `Calendar.java` and user close the ads then user should remains on `CalendarView.java` only.

Any positive response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't control the behavior of the Home button, that's a security breach.

Comment: Sorry but you cant do operation on HOME button, you need to find another way to deal with.

Comment: If you are asking such a lengthy question, then give a grammatically proper question with correct punctuation marks and all, other wise, it becomes impossible to read it .

Comment: You cannot override Homebutton's functionality, after 4.0 it wont work , and yes that's a security breach. You have to find another way for that.
And your question is hard to understand. Make it easy for better response

Comment: Thanks.. issue solved. i've used adlistener and then implement the required code in it's onDismissScreen() method.